# Load LLVM bitcode into module: cannot convert ‘std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module>’ to ‘llvm::Module*’

Tags: c++, llvm

I try to compile the minimal example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22241953/1889407)

```
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h>

using namespace llvm;
int main()
{
  LLVMContext context;
  SMDiagnostic error;
  Module *m = parseIRFile("hello.bc", error, context);

  if(m)
  {
    m->dump();
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

using

```
g++ myFile.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs all --system-libs` -std=c++11 -ldl -lpthread
```

and get

error: cannot convert ‘std::unique_ptr’ to ‘llvm::Module*’ in initialization

All examples and the llvm source itself everywhere uses llvm::Module *; so why do I get this error?

Note I use: LLVMVersion=3.6.0svn LLVM_CONFIGTIME= Thu Dec 18 10:51:37 CET 2014
Is it a problem with the 3.6 trunk? Should I opt for 3.5 branch?

Thx
Alex

Comment: Btw.: is there a llvm users list or forum? I could not find one; it seems there is only the llvm-dev list which is not adequate for my sort of questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `parseIRFile` gives you back a `unique_ptr<Module>` and there is no implicit conversion from `unique_ptr<Module>` to `Module*` (which is good!!). To fix, just use the correct type:

```
std::unique_ptr<Module> m = parseIRFile(..);
auto m = parseIRFile(..); // avoid all future type issues
```

Using `unique_ptr` for memory management is much smarter than using raw pointers - and this interface makes clear that you are responsible for ownership of `m`. This way, you don't have to remember to delete it.

If you really *really* want to use a raw pointer, just call [`release`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) on the returned object so that it no longer owns it:

```
Module* m = parseIRFile(..).release();
```

I only present that for completeness though - really prefer to keep your object a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm a bit irritated, because in the documentation there are everywhere Module*, Function* and so on. Should all these have to be replaced by std::unique_ptr<Module|Function|...>?

Comment: @alex Apparently. Believe me, we've all been there with the incorrect documentation... At least in this case, the compiler will clearly tell you where you're wrong.

Comment: llvm is huge and complex (from my point of view, I'm a bit out of c/c++ practice). Is there a place where llvm beginners can discuss? It seems there's no official list, I have several issues (e.g. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863706/llvm-out-of-source-pass-build-loadable-modules-not-supported-on-linux)), and the resonance is low.

Comment: @alex No clue - I don't know anything about LLVM.